# Adding image option in custom option magento 1.9

Tags: custom-options

In custom option is a drop-down option with an SKU etc... What I want to know is, is it possible to add image field in magento 1.9

Comment: Hello @irfan check this link --- https://inchoo.net/magento/add-custom-image-field-custom-options/

Comment: how to display images in frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you follow this link may be help you :-

**https://inchoo.net/magento/add-custom-image-field-custom-options**

And second :-

in your comment check this link ---

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155310/85907**

**`THANKS.`**